# Want to dequeue all the CSS and JS from /wp-content/uploads/xyz-folder

Tags: functions

I got one plugin which generates all CSS and JS on the /wp-content/uploads/xyz-folder,
I want to disable all this CSS and JS load on my website page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the names of the handles that the plugins use are, you can locate them using this code and then just use a simple `wp_dequeue_script` function.

```
function wp_inspect_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    echo '<pre><h1>Script Handles</h1><ul>';
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
        echo '<li>' . $handle . '</li>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul></pre>';
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp_inspect_scripts' );

function wp_inspect_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    echo '<pre><h1>Style Handles</h1><ul>';
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) :
        echo '<li>' . $handle . '</li>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</ul></pre>';
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wp_inspect_styles' );
```

Add the above code to your themes `functions.php` file for this to work.

Comment: Your code is helpful. But the thing is that plugin dynamically generate that names for some reason. And its vary page to page
So I want to find a way to prevent all the scripts and styles that stored on the /wp-content/uploads/xyz-folder

Hope you understand!

Comment: Might I ask what the plugin is called and what its use is?

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin dynamically generates script and style handles so that you can't use `wp_dequeue_script` and `wp_dequeue_style`, as you said in a [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372204/want-to-dequeue-all-the-css-and-js-from-wp-content-uploads-xyz-folder#comment541190_372206) on another [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/372206/1118), then you would need to fork the plugin, and remove the section of code that is doing that, or else wrap it in a conditional so that it only loads on the specific page in question. (Fork, because your changes will be overwritten by the next plugin update).